# Nginx doesn't find subdirectories and also doesn't run index.php at default directory

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm

I changed from Apache to Nginx and now I'm having some problems.

1. When I try to access to any folder as for example `http://devserver/monitor/web` where I have a Symfony project I get 404 error
2. When I try to access to `http://devserver` I get this message all the time `File not found.`

This is how my `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` file looks like:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  devserver;

    location / {
        root   /var/www/html;
        index  index.php;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           html;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

What is wrong there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have placed your `root` directives in the wrong places.

`root` should be defined in the `server` block, not in each `location` block. This is one of the [most common nginx misconfigurations](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/).

To resolve the issue, remove all of the `root` directives from each `location` block, and place the correct `root` directive within the `server` block, not within any `location`.

The only reason to have `root` in a `location` block is when you actually want a different document root for that `location`, such as for serving the nginx default error messages (as you are doing here).